# Are "incomplete monitors" and "cleared codes" the same thing?

Tags: obd-ii, code

I have heard both usages. I guess that they are the same thing but wasn't exactly sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically no.

"Codes" are errors that are set when a problem is detected, typically affecting emissions.

"incomplete monitors" are tests that have not fully run to verify the validity of certain systems - perhaps HO2S, EVAP, catalyst, etc.

An incomplete monitor is not saying there's a problem; it's just indicating that the ECU has not been driven through a complete drive cycle to verify the validity of the tests.  It doesn't pass an emissions inspection, but it doesn't fail either.

Comment: However, AFAICT, an incomplete monitor on a used car is a big red flag right? It most likely means that the owner has reset stuff to prevent codes from showing up during the test drive or while scanning the OBD 2 port.

Comment: Possibly, but not always.  There are two types of *codes*, pending and permanent.  You can "scan" for pending codes, even if there is no CEL or SES.  The same effect (incomplete monitors) could be caused by replacing a dead battery.